# HTML Merge table cells without creating a new one

Tags: html

I have an html like this:

```
<html>
 <body><br><br>Dear colleagues. 
    <table border=1>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Filename</th>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>URL</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
            <td>example.xml</td>
            <td>ID1234</td>
            <td><a href=https://example/view/780>https://example/view/780</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>example.xml</td>
            <td>ID456</td>
            <td><a href=https://example/view/780>https://example/view/780</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>example.xml</td>
            <td>ID678</td>
            <td><a href=https://example/view/780>https://example/view/780</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>example.xml</td>
            <td>ID891</td>
            <td><a href=https://example/view/780>https://example/view/780</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>example.xml</td>
            <td>ID112</td>
            <td><a href=https://example/view/780>https://example/view/780</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table><br>Regards :)
 </body>
</html>
```

[IMAGE OF INITIAL TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Vzb3.png)

And if the corresponding URL in each line is the same as the previous one I want them to merge. I've already tried rowspan but the existing URL'S move to the next column, like this:
[IMAGE - Error when I try to do rowspan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaB76.png)

```
<html>
    
    <body><br><br>Dear colleagues. 
        <table border=1>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Filename</th>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>URL</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tr>
                <td>example.xml</td>
                <td>ID1234</td>
                <td rowspan="5"><a href=https://example/view/780>https://example/view/780</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>example.xml</td>
                <td>ID456</td>
                <td><a href=https://example/view/780>https://example/view/780</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>example.xml</td>
                <td>ID678</td>
                <td><a href=https://example/view/780>https://example/view/780</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>example.xml</td>
                <td>ID891</td>
                <td><a href=https://example/view/780>https://example/view/780</a></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>example.xml</td>
                <td>ID112</td>
                <td><a href=https://example/view/780>https://example/view/780</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table><br>Regards :)
    </body>
 </html>
```

I want to look like this [IMAGE OF WHAT I WANT TO LOOK LIKE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GC7xH.png), without those addicional columns. Can someone help me pls?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want. I hope my answer is helpful to you.

```html
><br><br>Dear colleagues. 
    <table border=1>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Filename</th>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>URL</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan>example.xml</td>
            <td>ID1234</td>
            <td rowspan="5"><a href=https://example/view/780>https://example/view/780</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>example.xml</td>
            <td>ID456</td>
            
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>example.xml</td>
            <td>ID678</td>
            
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>example.xml</td>
            <td>ID891</td>
           
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>example.xml</td>
            <td>ID112</td>
        </tr>
    </table><br>Regards :)
```

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that this html code is generated by a for each in a datatable (so the last <td> is not my fault)